# How to add a pre-deployment task to deploy stage of a YAML based CICD pipeline

Tags: yaml, pipeline, cicd

We have a YAML CICD pipeline. CI part creates a build on a generic Azure agent.
CD part is run on a specific VM with additional tools/utilities. CD part will do some integration test.

We encountered issue that the VM has data left from previous run pipeline, adding clean up code to the CD part of the pipeline does not completely solve the issue because the pipeline could be cancelled manually.

We need something like pre-deployment task before downloading bits from pipeline artifacts, or post deployment task that will be invoked even the pipeline is cancelled manually.  Any document/examples for adding pre-deployment and post-deployment task to a YAML based CICD pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition, for example:

```bash
az group exists --name $(rgName)
```

Or alternatively, you can add a task to your stage that does what you are looking for with two tasks in the stage. The condition you can set to verify if the information exists and download that through the azure CLI command in the yaml pipeline. Furthermore, you can specify these tasks pre and post deployment.

Moreover, something like this would force all items to delete and ensures that all resources are deleted:

```bash
az vm delete \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myVM \
    --force-deletion
```

For more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/delete?tabs=portal2%2Ccli3%2Ccli4%2Cportal5